# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when calling other view in a navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView cell with some data.

When I select a cell I want the table view to redirect me to another view.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Multa *multa = [self.multas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DetalheMultaViewController *form = [[DetalheMultaViewController alloc] initWithMulta:multa];
    form.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:form animated:YES];
}
```

However, when in the last line I got this error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

And in the console I got this message(I understand what is saying but don't understand what's happening):

```
2012-09-16 17:11:25.719 Multas Sociais[5092:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetalheMultaViewController 0x7a46e10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fotoUrl.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1547052 0x1b0cd0a 0x1546f11 0xf2d032 0xe9ef7b 0xe9eeeb 0xeb9d60 0x7ac91a 0x1548e1a 0x14b2821 0x7ab46e 0x652e2c 0x6533a9 0x6535cb 0x652c1c 0x67956d 0x663d47 0x67a441 0x67a4f9 0x871c68 0x6314a1 0x63212b 0x8714c7 0x65a427 0x65a58c 0x65a5cc 0x3c2f 0x61d71d 0x61d952 0xea586d 0x151b966 0x151b407 0x147e7c0 0x147ddb4 0x147dccb 0x1f7a879 0x1f7a93e 0x58da9b 0x2608 0x2565)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

Ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When posting a crash question, please include more information.  No crash occurs in isolation; the debugger/console can contain a stack trace and probably tells you a lot more than you've posted here.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there were details of the error on the console. I've updated my question.

Comment: What is `fotoUrl`? Is it really defined as a property?

Comment: Yes it is. But thanks, I've already solved it with the answers that were provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have an old IBOutlet called `fotoURL` that is till connected to some object in your XIB file, whereas you removed the IBOutlet from your .h in your code since.

Edit your XIB file and remove the connection to the old `fotoURL` outlet.

If it's not sufficient, you may need to clean your project ("Product" menu, "Clean", or for better result hold the "alt" key and select "Clean Build Folder…") before building it again.

Answer (score 2):

I can suppose that you had had some `fotoUrl` IBOutlet property in `DetalheMultaViewController`'s xib earlier and you've linked it to some object. Later you've deleted this property from class interface, but a link in xib remained. So now, when framework loads xib, it tries to set a value, but there is no such value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your view controller when pushed is attempting to access `fotoURL`, which doesn't exist.  This could be within the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, but it possible that it is a setting in its nib file that is invalid; perhaps the `fotoURL` outlet existed in an earlier version of the nib and was never disconnected?